# Python: Replacing multiple for loops, multiple iterators

Tags: python, for-loop, python-itertools

I need your help. What is the most efficient way of substituting multiple nested for loops (over 5 nested loops into each other - 5 in the code example) if they all go through the same range (let's say from 1 to 10) and after the last for loop, at the bottom, i append every sum of the iterated items to the list. The code looks smth like this :

```
b=[]
for i in range(1, 11):
    for j in range(1, 11):
        for k in range(1, 11):
            for l in range(1, 11):
                for m in range(1, 11):
                    b.append(i+j+k+l+m)
```

It is obviously not memory-friendly and will take some time. As far as i know, itertools can not really help here either. So how could it be helped?

Answer (score 2):

use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product
b = [sum(item) for item in product(range(1, 11), repeat=5)]
```

You may want to make b generator, so that it is evaluated lazily

```
b = (sum(item) for item in product(range(1, 11), repeat=5))
```

Comment: A cleaner way would be to use `map`: `b = map(sum, product(range(1, 11), repeat=5))`

Comment: @HarishRajagopal, this is a matter of personal preference and subject to a lot of discussions, incl here on SO (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979290/4046632), at the same time Guido has clearly [stated his preference for list comprehension](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) .

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links! I found the discussions very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using recursive programming. This happens when a function calls itself to do the same task with different parameters.

```py
def someIteration(b, i, j, k, l, m):
    for i in range(1,11):
        b.append(i+j+k+l+m)
    if (Certain task done):
         return b
    else:
        someIteration(b, i, j, k, l, m)
```

I dont think this function will work directly, I recommend to do some research in recursive programming. It's a really interesting paradigm, mostly used in ai!

pros:

- its very code efficient

cons:

- when the stack is full, it will crash (this rarely happens, most of the time due to a bug.)